# paypal with ActiveMerchant

Tags: paypal, activemerchant

I am integrating paypal service in my application using Activemerchant.

Now I want to know how to use ActiveMerchant to make payment to Bank or Credit card ?

for example:
I am seller and I want to pay some amount to somebody. I want to pay such amount which will be credited in others bank account or credit card directly ?

Please reply me as early as possible.
And also suggest me any configuration which i should make in test accounts, if any.

Comment: This isn't directly related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See railscasts about paypal and active merchant